# Ionic - "camera cancelled" when allowEdit is true

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, camera, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to facilitate cropping an image before uploading it in my Ionic app.  It works fine when I pick an image from the image gallery but it fails with the reason **"camera cancelled"** when a photo is directly shot from the camera.

I'm using Cordova's basic camera plugin - cordova-plugin-camera.  Here's the relevant snippet of my code:

```
$scope.openCamera = function () {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(
        onSuccess(),
        onFailure(),
        {
            allowEdit: true,
            quality: 100,
            sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
            targetWidth: 100,
            targetHeight: 100,
            correctOrientation: true
        }
    );
}
```

The camera captures photos correctly and also shows the image to let me select area to crop.  However, it fails and enters onFailure() instead of onSuccess().
onFailure() callback prints the error "camera cancelled".  This bug came on 3 of 5 phones of various Android builds I tested it on.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34423861/cordova-camera-getpicture-fails-with-camera-cancelled)

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? I am having a similar problem.

Comment: @MarkA.Rupert I ended up using cordova-plugin-crop to do that.  Basically, my onSuccess() function invokes the crop plugin, which handles targetWidth, targetHeight, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using cordova-plugin-crop as a workaround to get the result I wanted, across all Android/iOS devices.  Here's a snippet of my updated code:

```
$scope.openCamera = function () {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(
        onSuccess(),
        onFailure(),
        {
            quality: 100,
            destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI
        }
    );
}

function onSuccess(fileURI) {
            plugins.crop.promise(fileURI, {
                quality: 100,
                destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
                allowEdit: true,
                targetWidth: 100,
                targetHeight: 100,
            }).then(function success(newPath) {
                // Call API to upload the file
            }).catch(function fail(err) {
                // Handle failure
            })
        }
```

Hope this helps!